# Customizing Persistent Bottom Sheet STATE_EXPANDED height or offset

Tags: android, android-support-library, offset, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

Like the titles said, is there anyway to customize the size/height/offset of the official bottomSheet (Support library 23.x.x) when it is in STATE_EXPANDED state?

There is a class `BottomSheetBehavior` but I can't find anything about height or offset.

What I want is get a similar behavior like Google Maps:
[image: like you can see in this gif]

Comment: Can I know why vote down??? do you have the answer?, need the code that I have been working on(a big one)? or its a duplicated question? guess not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging on Android code and searching I got it:

You can do it modifying default `BottomSheetBehavior` adding one more stat with following steps:

1. Create a Java class and extend it from `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>`
2. Copy paste code from default `BottomSheetBehavior` file to your new one.
3. Modify the method `clampViewPositionVertical` with the following code:

   ```
   @Override
   public int clampViewPositionVertical(View child, int top, int dy) {
       return constrain(top, mMinOffset, mHideable ? mParentHeight : mMaxOffset);
   }

   int constrain(int amount, int low, int high) {
       return amount < low ? low : (amount > high ? high : amount);
   }
   ```
4. Add a new state

   public static final int STATE_ANCHOR_POINT = X;
5. Modify the next methods: `onLayoutChild`, `onStopNestedScroll`, `BottomSheetBehavior<V> from(V view)` and `setState` (optional)

I'm going to add those modified methods and a [link to the example project](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior)

```
public boolean onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, int layoutDirection) {
    // First let the parent lay it out
    if (mState != STATE_DRAGGING && mState != STATE_SETTLING) {
        if (ViewCompat.getFitsSystemWindows(parent) &&
                !ViewCompat.getFitsSystemWindows(child)) {
            ViewCompat.setFitsSystemWindows(child, true);
        }
        parent.onLayoutChild(child, layoutDirection);
    }
    // Offset the bottom sheet
    mParentHeight = parent.getHeight();
    mMinOffset = Math.max(0, mParentHeight - child.getHeight());
    mMaxOffset = Math.max(mParentHeight - mPeekHeight, mMinOffset);

    //if (mState == STATE_EXPANDED) {
    //    ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, mMinOffset);
    //} else if (mHideable && mState == STATE_HIDDEN...
    if (mState == STATE_ANCHOR_POINT) {
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, mAnchorPoint);
    } else if (mState == STATE_EXPANDED) {
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, mMinOffset);
    } else if (mHideable && mState == STATE_HIDDEN) {
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, mParentHeight);
    } else if (mState == STATE_COLLAPSED) {
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, mMaxOffset);
    }
    if (mViewDragHelper == null) {
        mViewDragHelper = ViewDragHelper.create(parent, mDragCallback);
    }
    mViewRef = new WeakReference<>(child);
    mNestedScrollingChildRef = new WeakReference<>(findScrollingChild(child));
    return true;
}


public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, V child, View target) {
    if (child.getTop() == mMinOffset) {
        setStateInternal(STATE_EXPANDED);
        return;
    }
    if (target != mNestedScrollingChildRef.get() || !mNestedScrolled) {
        return;
    }
    int top;
    int targetState;
    if (mLastNestedScrollDy > 0) {
        //top = mMinOffset;
        //targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
        int currentTop = child.getTop();
        if (currentTop > mAnchorPoint) {
            top = mAnchorPoint;
            targetState = STATE_ANCHOR_POINT;
        }
        else {
            top = mMinOffset;
            targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
        }
    } else if (mHideable && shouldHide(child, getYVelocity())) {
        top = mParentHeight;
        targetState = STATE_HIDDEN;
    } else if (mLastNestedScrollDy == 0) {
        int currentTop = child.getTop();
        if (Math.abs(currentTop - mMinOffset) < Math.abs(currentTop - mMaxOffset)) {
            top = mMinOffset;
            targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
        } else {
            top = mMaxOffset;
            targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
        }
    } else {
        //top = mMaxOffset;
        //targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
        int currentTop = child.getTop();
        if (currentTop > mAnchorPoint) {
            top = mMaxOffset;
            targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
        }
        else {
            top = mAnchorPoint;
            targetState = STATE_ANCHOR_POINT;
        }
    }
    if (mViewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(child, child.getLeft(), top)) {
        setStateInternal(STATE_SETTLING);
        ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(child, new SettleRunnable(child, targetState));
    } else {
        setStateInternal(targetState);
    }
    mNestedScrolled = false;
}

public final void setState(@State int state) {
    if (state == mState) {
        return;
    }
    if (mViewRef == null) {
        // The view is not laid out yet; modify mState and let onLayoutChild handle it later
        /**
         * New behavior (added: state == STATE_ANCHOR_POINT ||)
         */
        if (state == STATE_COLLAPSED || state == STATE_EXPANDED ||
                state == STATE_ANCHOR_POINT ||
                (mHideable && state == STATE_HIDDEN)) {
            mState = state;
        }
        return;
    }
    V child = mViewRef.get();
    if (child == null) {
        return;
    }
    int top;
    if (state == STATE_COLLAPSED) {
        top = mMaxOffset;
    } else if (state == STATE_ANCHOR_POINT) {
        top = mAnchorPoint;
    } else if (state == STATE_EXPANDED) {
        top = mMinOffset;
    } else if (mHideable && state == STATE_HIDDEN) {
        top = mParentHeight;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal state argument: " + state);
    }
    setStateInternal(STATE_SETTLING);
    if (mViewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(child, child.getLeft(), top)) {
        ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(child, new SettleRunnable(child, state));
    }
}


public static <V extends View> BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike<V> from(V view) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    if (!(params instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout");
    }
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) params)
            .getBehavior();
    if (!(behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The view is not associated with BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike");
    }
    return (BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike<V>) behavior;
}
```

You can even use callbacks with `behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike.BottomSheetCallback() {....`

**And here is how its looks like:**
[[image: CustomBottomSheetBehavior]]

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure but I guess this is your answer:

```
    View bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
    final BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            // React to state change
            Log.e("onStateChanged", "onStateChanged:" + newState);
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                //do something
            } else {
                //do something
            }
        }

        //Here is what you want
        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            // React to dragging events
            Log.e("onSlide", "the  offset "+ slideOffset );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ty for the answer but this is not the answer. The code above if useful when you want to listen when the bottomSheet has reached some of its states but you can't change there its behavior. I found how to do it but I'm a little bussy now, I will publish the answer in some hours.