# For a persistent bottomsheet, how can you achieve a gesture (swipe down) from expanded state to half expanded?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, kotlin

I'm using a bottomsheet that allows for a half expanded state. From a collapsed state I can swipe up the bottomsheet to a half expanded state. A subsequent swipe up results in a fully expanded state. If I swipe down from the expanded state the bottomsheet drops all the way to collapsed and misses the half expanded state. What do I need to do to prevent the skipping of the half collapsed state?

Comment: The only answer here isn't really helping me, did you ever manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your purpose by editing default `BottomSheetBehavior` by adding one more stat, you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377725/customizing-persistent-bottom-sheet-state-expanded-height-or-offset) it may help you  , or use a `CustomBottomSheetBehavior` available [here](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior)